# Proof Verification that $\lim(x_{n})= 0$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_n$ is the sequence defined as $x_n := 1/\ln(n+1)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am self studying real analysis and looking for confirmation of whether or not whether the following proof is appropriate or whether I am missing something.

Prove that $\lim(x_{n})= 0$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_n$ is the sequence defined as $x_n := 1/\ln(n+1)$

Scratch Work:
$$1/\ln(n+1) < \epsilon$$
$$\implies1/\epsilon<\ln(n+1)$$
$$\implies e^{1/\epsilon}-1<n$$
Where $\epsilon >0$

Proof begins:
Let  $x_n$ be the sequence $x_n := 1/\ln(n+1)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Since $e^{1/\epsilon}-1$ is a real number, the Archimedean property entails that there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $e^{1/\epsilon}-1<n$ and there exists a $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\ge K$ and $e^{1/\epsilon}-1<K$. Then we have for some $n\ge K$ and for any $\epsilon > 0$:

$$e^{1/\epsilon}-1<n$$
$$\implies 1/\ln(n+1) < \epsilon$$
$$\implies \left\lvert 1/\ln(n+1)\right\rvert < \epsilon$$
$$\implies \left\lvert 1/\ln(n+1)-0\right\rvert < \epsilon$$

Where the second to last line follows since $1/\ln(n+1) \ge 0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, $\lim(x_{n})= 0$. QED.

I'm sure there are proofs that are much faster than this one, but as I am currently starting to work through these types of questions, I would first like to know if I have the basics down.

Comment: Your proof is fine !

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Congrats your proof is correct

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine conceptually. However, I would note a few formal points:

- You write "Since $e^{1/\epsilon}-1$ is a real number, ...", but you have not defined the quantity $\epsilon$ in your proof yet. You should start your proof with "Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary." or something similar (and then remove the "and for any $\epsilon>0$" you write later, of course).
- You never use the existence of the $n$ you obtain by the Archimedean property, you only use  $K$. Therefore, you can remove anything regarding $n$ from this sentence.
- Minor point: It should be: "Then we have for **any** $n\geq K$ ...", "some" may be mistaken for "there exists an $n$ such that..."
- Depending on your level, you might want to write a short explanation why taking logarithms preserves an inequality.